# Finding duplicates in an array of objects

Tags: javascript

Hope everyone is having a good Christmas.

First of all, this is working code in a production environment.

I recently wrote some code for work.

The goal is to find `users` that contain more than one `role`. On the frontend, if a `user` has more than one `role`, the person using the program will see a message suggesting that they remove one of these roles.

Here is the code that I wrote. Mind you, I have changed some of the values so that anything sensitive is removed:

```
usersWithMultipleRoles() {
      /**
       * Make a flat map of all the users from each role.
       * Each entry is an object with a roleId
       */
      const users = this.roles.flatMap(r => {
        return r.users.map(value => {
          return { roleId: r.id, user: value }
        })
      })

      /**
       * Use reduce to create an array of objects.
       * Each object is keyed by the user's ID,
       * and its value is the roles that each user is in.
       */
      const lookup = users.reduce((acc, value) => {
        acc[value.user.id] = acc[value.user.id] || []
        acc[value.user.id].push(value.roleId)
        return acc
      }, [])

      /**
       * Finally, return an array of users that have
       * multiple roles.
       */
      const usersWithManyRoles = []

      lookup.forEach((value, key) => {
        if (value.length > 1) {
          usersWithManyRoles.push({
            userId: key,
            userInfo: users.find(value => value.user.id === key).user,
            roles: value,
          })
        }
      })

      return usersWithManyRoles
    },
```

The following is what I would expect if a `user` has more than one `role` assigned.

```
[
  {
    userId: 127,
    userInfo: { User Object },
    roles: [2, 6],
  },
  ...

]
```

Just so you know, there is nothing wrong with this code. It returns exactly what I'm looking for.

#### What I would change

The only thing I can think about changing is the structure of the response from the first mapping function, the `flatMap` function.

#### My question to you

How would *you* write this function? How can I improve it? And what should I read to make better functions in the future?

Comment: "Just so you know, there is nothing wrong with this code. It returns exactly what I'm looking for." Good, because this site is for working code!

Answer (score 3):

- I do not understand the `flatMap`. Does it just loop through and return pairs of user and ID? If it is a loop, you can just write it that way.
- I'm not sure `users.reduce` call is appropriate since you're using it for side-effects (pushing to array). I think a `for..of` or `forEach` loop is easier to understand than a more complicated `reduce` function that passes `acc` around.
- `users.find` is ok for small arrays but finding over large arrays will be slow and so a map data structure should be used for efficiency.
- I would avoid code like `|| []` for readability. Maybe it is a standard idiom. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614134/create-array-and-push-into-it-in-one-line

Comment: > I do not understand the flatMap. 

Sometimes, a `role` may not actually have any users assigned, so the flatMap will remove these empty arrays. 

After reading the answers written so far, I'm questioning the need for a `flatMap` though.

Answer (score 1):

For optimal performance, you want to use a [hash table](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-hash-table-associative-array-hashing-in-js/) for your data structure. Hash tables have amortized O(1) time performance for insertion and lookup. Use the user ID as they keys, and the values are a collection of roles for each user. Total of O(n).

Pseudocode:

```
hashtable = HashTable()

for user, role in table:
    hashtable[user].append(role)

for user, roles in hashtable:
    if len(roles) > 1:
        yield user
```

Alternatively, you should be able to roll this into a single SQL query with a JOIN, followed by COUNT and GROUP BY. https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/count-with-group-by.php

Comment: Thank you. I've been reading more about hash tables over the past couple of days, so I think I would like to try this. 

I think this might also make it faster when an admin adds and removes users in different `roles`. If it's a new user then it just adds the user to the hash table; if the user exists, it adds the role to the user.

Comment: That said, the SQL query might make a bit more sense in the long term. I should just add a function in the Laravel backend to return that count in the response whenever a PUT / GET request is received.

Comment: The SQL query only makes sense if you are using a SQL backend. For simple manipulation of javascript arrays and maps it's not necessary.

Comment: Well, we already use SQL queries for parts of our backend in the Laravel / Eloquent code, things that built in Laravel / Eloquent queries cannot do ( or are just too complicated to do outside of SQL ). I'm not an expert on backend stuff by any means, so I'm just saying what was told to me by my counterpart.

Answer (score 1):

I think your map/reduce are a fine approach.

You could combine the first two into a single pipeline (or all three), as the intermediate variable (`users`), besides being imprecisely named, isn't that useful.

I would say the third pipeline could be brought into line with the same techniques. Instead of array/push:

```
const usersWithManyRoles = []

  lookup.forEach((value, key) => {
    if (value.length > 1) {
      usersWithManyRoles.push({
        userId: key,
        userInfo: users.find(value => value.user.id === key).user,
        roles: value,
      })...
```

You could use `filter` and then `map`. Therefore:

```
const usersWithManyRoles = 
  lookup
   .filter((value) => value.length > 1)
   .map((value, key) => {
      return {
        userId: key,
        userInfo: users.find(value => value.user.id === key).user,
        roles: value,
...
```

It may be possible to reduce the amount of data you are shuffling around... I'm not sure how much of that you actually need. If you just need a list of user_ids, a different approach could be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

### Use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

The [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) `lookup` where you add items by user id is in effect a map by user id. You can get all the information needed to find users with multiple roles while building that array. There is no need to process that array again. However rather than use an array use a hash map.

JavaScript has many hash map options [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), [WeakMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap), and [WeakSet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakSet). In this case you can use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to index by user id. While adding to the map you can check the number of roles. Each user that gets more than one role is added to the result array (users with multiple roles).

This way you can get the array of users with multiple roles in one pass and keep memory use to a minimum. 1 object per user.

### Example

**Note:** example has modified input and output, thus is an example rather than a rewrite.

The objects returned seam to name the user `userInfo` and include the user id as `userId`. You are in effect duplicating data for no reason. Thus the example changes returned objects from `{userId: user.id, userInfo: user, roles: [role]}` to `{user, roles: [role]}` No data is lost from the returned array of users with multiple roles.

Also the function takes an reference to array of roles, rather than is a function of (unknown) object (ref to roles is `this.roles`).

```
function usersWithMultipleRoles(roles) {
    const rolesByUser = new Map(), multipleRoles = [];
    roles.forEach(role => {
        role.forEach(user => {
            const userRoles = rolesByUser.get(user.id);
            if (userRoles) {
                userRoles.roles.push(role);
                userRoles.roles.length === 2 && multipleRoles.push(userRoles);
            } else {
                rolesByUser.set(user.id, {user, roles: [role]});
            }
        });
    });
    return multipleRoles;
}
```